# Local instance of SQL Server 2017 min requirements

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have Windows 7 running on my machine (I know it's old) and when I try to install SQL Server 2017 using the setup utility, I get this error:

> The operating system on this computer does not meet the min requirements for SQL Server 2017. To determine the min required OS supported for this SQL server release, see the hardware and software requirements.

This is the link provided: [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#top_principal)

I don't see anything there that stands out that my machine does not have. I know people have installed SQL Server 2017 on Windows 7 boxes, so that can't be the issue.

I tried changing the compatibility mode by right clicking the setup file and properties too, to Windows 7 but I still can't get passed that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at the link you provided Windows 7 is actually not in the list of OS supported? [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32b9869e-435e-442a-ae16-82a5f3b27b24/sql-server-2017-express-install-on-windows-7-pro-64bit-sp1?forum=sqlgetstarted) it's also mentioned SQl Server 2017 can only be installed on Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 and later versions.

Comment: Ya, thats what my understanding is also, but there are peeps that have actually installed SQL 2017 on windows 7.  If that still cant be done...  I wonder what is the last version of SQL that can go with windows 7.

Comment: @Sarah The link you posted has the information you seek. You can change the version information on the left side - it will show you details for 2014 and later versions. 2014 is the last version to support Windows 7. And if you "know peeps", you should ask them how they did it.

Comment: @Smor, I wouldn't be asking questions if I had found the answers in the link or from those peeps.  But thanks for your comment.

Comment: @elelle, I think I can get SQL 2017 only management studio installed and run a local SQL 2012 version on windows 7. I think that will solve the issue for now, thanks for your help on this. Appreciate it.